# JASIG CAS CORS what should happen when Origin == "null"?

Tags: spring, security, proxy, cors, cas

I am using a CAS server to secure my Spring applications which includes REST and HttpInvoker APIs.

When an application redirects to a CAS server in a different domain we get CORS 
'issues'. I have added the eBay Cors-Filter https://github.com/eBay/cors-filter to the applications and the CAS server.

However...

when the application redirects to the CAS server for authentication, the Origin header is changed to 'null'. This is due to a "privacy-sensitive" context noted in the CORS spec (page 14, section 7.3).

...and, now at last...the question!

If the server receives an Origin header of 'null' can it proceed as normal, just returning 'null' in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Does this break anything?

Is it unsafe?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe you can return `null` or the wildcard `*` to allow any origin.

> Does this break anything?

If you're only returning `null` when `Origin: null` is received then it shouldn't affect anything else.

> Is it unsafe?

I'm not familiar with CAS, however as long as you aren't sending `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` too, and your CAS isn't restricted by IP or on the local network only, then this doesn't open up your system any more than anonymous access does. See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/44058/8340) for technical details.

If you are, then setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` will allow other domains and origins to read data from CORS that the user visits, using their cookies for CAS.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing `null` origins **is** unsafe.  [This blog post](https://yassineaboukir.com/blog/cors-exploitation-data-exfiltration-when-allowed-origin-is-set-to-null/) does a pretty good job of breaking down why.  The short version is, it enables a form of CSRF. An allowed origin of `null` means "any page that redirects to me" (or any code running from a `file:///` URL, but that's another topic).

Let's say your app at `app.example.com` uses a service at `service.example.com`, protected with CAS on `auth.example.com`. Also, let's assume you set up `service` with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null` so that you can make a fetch from `app` that points to `auth` with a  redirect to `service`. Got all that?  Good, you make a fetch for `auth.example.com/cas/login?service=service.example.com`, login happens (session cookie set on `auth.example.com`), redirect happens (session cookie set on `service.example.com`), `app` gets data from `service`.  Because of your `Access-Control` headers, the browser lets your app read the response.

Now, imagine that you visit a malicious page (`evil.com/hello`) that knows about your service.  They run a 302 page on `evil.com/redir` that points to `service.example.com`.  Now, this malicious code can fetch `evil.com/redir` with `credentials="include"`. The browser will request the redirect page, getting a `302` with ACA-Origin=`https://evil.com` and ACA-Credentials=true, `Location` of `service.example.com`. The browser follows the 302, requesting `service.example.com` and including the relevant session cookie.  In this request, `Origin` is set to `null` but you've whitelisted that value, so your service sends an ACA-Origin value of `null` and the browser lets the (malicious) requesting code see the response. You just leaked authenticated data from your service to the injected script, which can send it home to the attacker.